# How to align elements in a tabset using fluidRow

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have my plot next to summary statistics inside of a `tabPanel`. I am trying to use `fluidRow` to do this but I cant seem to get the elements to align side by side. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for random distribution app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select the random distribution type ----
      radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                   c("Normal" = "norm",
                     "Uniform" = "unif",
                     "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                     "Exponential" = "exp")),

      # br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing ----
      br(),

      # Input: Slider for the number of observations to generate ----
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000)
      ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
        tabPanel("Plot", 
          fluidRow(
            column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("plot"))),
            column(6,wellPanel(verbatimTextOutput("summary")))  
          )           
        )
      )

# Define server logic for random distribution app ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive expression to generate the requested distribution ----
  # This is called whenever the inputs change. The output functions
  # defined below then use the value computed from this expression
  d <- reactive({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)

    dist(input$n)
  })



  # Generate a plot of the data ----
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- input$dist
    n <- input$n

    hist(d(),
         main = paste("r", dist, "(", n, ")", sep = ""),
         col = "#75AADB", border = "white")
  })

  # Generate a summary of the data ----
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(d())
  })



}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your Code...output is below picture...

[image]